# Groups roles & capabilities

Tags: users, user-roles, capabilities

OK here's the situation I need to play with

- I have a business with multiple departments. Within those departments, there will be multiple users each with individual logins.
- Each department should only be able to edit specific page(s) [their department page]
- They should also be able and edit their own (custom)posts.

The issue comes with multiple logins, otherwise I'd be able to just have them edit their own content and not others. But because I need groups of users to share editor rights, I am not sure how best to do this?

Any solutions plugin or no out there?

Comment: Role Scoper - https://wordpress.org/plugins/role-scoper/ This plugin may help you

Comment: And also checkout - User Role Editor - https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/ to enable multiple roles for an user.

Comment: I have tried both of these but they don't solve the problem as they only look at Roles and Capabilities and not groups of users and edit rights for content.

Comment: If Role Scoper doesn't fit your needs, the easiest way to set up custom group permissions is to register custom post types for each group. Then, give a role to each department such that they can add/edit/delete whichever post types they're supposed to access. Letting them edit specific Pages is where things get too tricky. Try CPT archives instead of Pages and see if that gives you the permalink structure you want and also lets you enable permissions as needed.